# MSCRM Identify Quick View attributes on form attribute collection

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

On a form in Microsoft Dynamics CRM you can place a Quick View Form to show information from a related parent entity.
I use javascript to dynamically retrieve all attributes on the form:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attribute, index) { ... }
```

As of CRM 2016, this method gives me all attributes available, **including** attributes from the parent entity.
Is there a way to identify which of the returned attributes that actually belong to the parent entity and are only available because of the QV Form placed on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either filtering the fields in advance or using the .getParent().getId() with each attribute, comparing the main form entity id with  Quick view entity id.